# Transforming JSON into PostgreSQL table

Tags: json, postgresql

I've got this JSON data, and what I want to do is organize its keys and values into a table format:

```
my_json = '[
    {
        "home": "team1",
        "away": "team2",
        "odds": {
            "periods": {
                "1": {
                    "scoring_types": {
                        "1": {
                            "bet_types": {
                                "1": {
                                    "outcomes": {
                                        "1": 1.85,
                                        "3": 3.85,
                                        "2": 6.50
                                    },
                                    "param": null
                                },
                                "2": {
                                    "outcomes": {
                                        "1": 1.9,
                                        "2": 1.9
                                    },
                                    "param": 8.5
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]'
```

The resulting table should look like this:

| home | away | scoring_type_id | periods_id | bet_types | outcomes | param | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | null | 1.85 |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | null | 6.5 |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | null | 3.85 |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 8.5 | 1.9 |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 8.5 | 1.9 |

The keys representing column names: `home,  away , scoring_type_id , periods_id, bet_types , outcomes,  param`, `value` are consistent and always present. However, keys that aren't column names can vary in number, such as multiple types of `period`s and `scoring_type`s. The goal is to generate a row for each decimal value found under `outcomes`, while maintaining the parent keys as displayed in the table.

Currently, I've managed to write a query for the first three columns, but I'm struggling with accessing nested keys/values.

```
SELECT
  home,
  away,
  (st).key AS scoring_type_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    home,
    away,
    json_each_text(odds->'scoring_types') AS st
  FROM
    json_to_recordset(my_json
  ) AS data(home TEXT, away TEXT, odds JSON)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to [`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) all the way down the structure.

1. Use `jsonb` to keep your tables light, [indexable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING), quick and easy to query thanks to [additional functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE). If that's not an option for you, you can switch all functions below to their regular `json` variant by [removing the `b`](https://dbfiddle.uk/HdRZv28v).
2. I'm using `,` to [shorten `cross join lateral` on purpose](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html), but keep in mind commas are often frowned upon even if you use them with care.

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/YjHar8os)

```sql
select elem->>'home' as home,
       elem->>'away' as away,
       scoring_type_id,
       periods_id,
       bet_type_id as bet_types,
       outcomes,
       bet_type->>'param' as param,
       value 
from my_table
,jsonb_array_elements(my_json) as a(elem)
,jsonb_each(elem->'odds') as e(e_key,periods)
,jsonb_each(periods)      as p1(periods_id,period)
,jsonb_each(period)       as p2(p2_key,scoring_types)
,jsonb_each(scoring_types)as s1(scoring_type_id,scoring_type)
,jsonb_each(scoring_type) as s2(s2_key,bet_types)
,jsonb_each(bet_types)    as b1(bet_type_id,bet_type)
,jsonb_each(bet_type->'outcomes')     as b2(outcomes,value)
```

| home | away | scoring_type_id | periods_id | bet_types | outcomes | param | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | *null* | 1.85 |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | *null* | 6.50 |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | *null* | 3.85 |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 8.5 | 1.9 |
| team1 | team2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 8.5 | 1.9 |